# Generate sequence in Oracle based on length of column

Tags: oracle, function, output, sequence

I need to generate sequence in Oracle based on length of column and incremental of 2.

```
For example:
Select comp_name from table_a
Output: COGNIZANT
```

So I need to generate sequence:

```
Generate_sequence ( min number , length (comp_name), incremental)
```

Meaning:  sequence min val 1 , max value 9 and incremental of 2
i.e  (1, 9,2)

Here 9 because our output is cognizant whose length is 9

Output from sequence geneated should be

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: Are you talking about using a SEQUENCE object or just generating a list of numbers with the criteria?  You want to use a pl/sql function?

Comment: Yes, I am taking on generating a list of numbers based on the criteria.  Pl/SQL function would be great if we can get otherwise if normal SQL queries also is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the user-defined function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION generate_series(
  i_start IN NUMBER,
  i_end   IN NUMBER,
  i_step  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_steps CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := FLOOR((i_end - i_start)/i_step);
BEGIN
  FOR step_num IN 0 .. v_steps LOOP
    PIPE ROW (i_start + i_step * step_num);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then use it in a table collection expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(generate_series(1,3,0.7));
```

Which outputs:

> | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 1.7 |
> | 2.4 |

---

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (comp_name) AS
SELECT 'COGNIZANT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT comp_name,
       s.column_value
FROM   table_a
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(generate_series(1, LENGTH(comp_name), 2)) s
```

Outputs:

> | COMP_NAME | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | COGNIZANT | 1 |
> | COGNIZANT | 3 |
> | COGNIZANT | 5 |
> | COGNIZANT | 7 |
> | COGNIZANT | 9 |
> | ABCD | 1 |
> | ABCD | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d2d916436a4d56b25021887b1887c6a)*

Comment: After seeing such smart solutions, I always think, Why SO don't allow more than 1 upvote.  This certainly deserves 100 upvotes.

Comment: Aggred @ankit Bajpai